# Synch Clock Per Request

Tags: centos7, ntp, chrony

I am using CentOS 7.4, and NTP is replaced by Chrony.

I just wonder whether Chrony has something similar to ntpdate, which can be used to synch clock per request (from command line, etc)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, understand what software running would be seriously affected by jumps from stepping the time. It may be safer to wait until you can bring databases down.

Start chronyd, wait a few seconds for the first measurement, and [make it step the remaining correction with the makestep commmand.](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/manual.html#makestep-command)  Usually chrony.conf will contain a makestep directive to step the first updates anyway, but the makestep command can be at any time.

```
systemctl start chronyd
sleep 10
chronyc makestep
```

[There is an option to set clock once and exit. Similar to ntpd -q, even is the same -q option.](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/faq.html#_does_code_chronyd_code_have_an_ntpdate_mode) However, it only works while chronyd is not running, which it should be. So I prefer makestep, although the -Q option is nice to get the offset of something not in the configuration.

> ### Does chronyd have an ntpdate mode?
>
> Yes. With the -q option chronyd
>   will set the system clock once and exit. With the -Q option it will
>   print the measured offset without setting the clock. If you don’t want
>   to use a configuration file, NTP servers can be specified on the
>   command line. For example:
>
> `chronyd -q 'pool pool.ntp.org iburst'`

These are not your only options. You can trigger a burst of measurements, or wait on slew instead of stepping the time, or some combination of the above.  [See this chrony-users thread comparing burst and waitsync.](http://chrony-users.chrony.tuxfamily.narkive.com/6nuc6vtF/which-command-is-better-to-force-chrony-to-synchronize-time-right-now-chronyc-burst-or-chronyc)

Comment: Although I have more questions around your answer, your answer did answer what I have asked in this post!  I will create another post.  Thanks!